# how to get wso2 is webservice access token after SSO

Tags: web-services, wso2, token

after configure the SP on WSo2 IS platform, I successful login via SAML2 SSO, then I need to call some WSo2 IS web services, but the web services need to authenticate first, now I hard code admin/admin to call the authentication web service, then I can call getRole or getPermission or other web service successful, but I think I must get some access token after SSO instead of hard code user credential, and how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have written I can understand that you are trying accomplish OAuth Bearer Token-based Authentication. Please refer to link[1] and link[2] for more details. Link [2], shows an example of how it is used.

[1]. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/04/access-token-based-authentication-and-authorization-using-xacml/
[2]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS410/OAuth+Bearer+Token-based+Authentication+for+SCIM+Endpoints

Comment: you mean after login with SAML2 SSO, I need to get OAuth access token first, then call web service with this token? I saw some articles what you provide before, but I can't understand the process clearly, do you have some sample code about this?

Comment: Log in to IS, In your SP configuration , under "Inbound Authentication Configuration" > "OAuthe/OpenID connect configuration" click configure and fill the required fields, the call back url doesn't matter. After that you can get OAuthClient Key and OAuth Secret key. Use those in http headers when you are requesting.